# How to use SMARTBANNER (AdMob) and be sure to show it

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I decided to put a SMARTBANNER with AdMob on my app.
As it is stated from the documentation:
[smart-banners sizes](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/smart-banners)
on Android, portrait, I reserved 50 dp of height. So I just reserved an empty linear layout for it, it worked for me in past apps:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutAd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

And then used the method:

```
   private void createAdView() {
        if (C.AD_ON) {
            ad_view = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, C.AD_APPLICATION_ID);
            LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.layoutAd);
            l.addView (ad_view);
            AdRequest a = new AdRequest();
            ad_view.loadAd(a);
        }
    }
```

Now, while generally this simple method works, in this case I get an error:

```
Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 90>, Has: <480, 50>
```

??? 480x90? 480x50? I cannot find any of these sizes in the previous table... Where do they come from?
Anyway, the ad does not show.

I then tried to reserve 90dp instead of 50dp, and the ad shows correctly, leaving an emtpy space of... guess what... about 40dp.

At this point a question arose to me: before, with my previous apps, everything worked on phones. I thought that everything was adapting to different screen sizes and densities. Now I am scared that actually many of my ads couldn't show because the ad was expecting 90dp instead of 50dp, or whatever other number.

Actually the ONLY reason for which I decided to put a SMARTBANNER was that I thought to be free from this kind of problems!

Now... What should I do to make this work correctly on EVERY possible screen and be reasonably sure that it won't fail on some density or some size? Should I detect by myself what device am I running on, and then reserve 50, 90 or maybe 55 dp programmatically? This sounds absurd to me!

Isn't there such a function as some "WRAP_CONTENT" that is appliable to the banner, so that I don't have to manually specify 90 or 50 pixels, but just expect the correct banner to show and the layout to adapt to it?

Thank you.

Comment: This is an odd case, the above code should have worked. What device did you try this on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you actually tried `WRAP_CONTENT` for `layout_height` on the smart banner? That is the solution and recommended practice.

Comment: Oh my....
Am I a complete idiot or what? I thought that I already tried and some how did not work, so I switched to a fixed size. Now I tried back and there's no real reason for not choosing wrap_content...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to used a fixed height (and not use the recommended WRAP_CONTENT) you'll have to go the route of providing a dimension for every screen size. I use the following dimensions but be warned, these could change if the implementation of smartbanner changes.

```
/values/dimens
<dimen name="ad_min_height">50dp</dimen>

/values-land/dimens
<dimen name="ad_min_height">32dp</dimen>

/values-large-land-v11/dimens
<dimen name="ad_min_height">90dp</dimen>

/values-large-v11/dimens
<dimen name="ad_min_height">90dp</dimen>
```